# Angular : Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular

hello everyone i'm trying to use the openWeb API to get some data,
I got the data  to show through the console but so hard for me to display the data.

**ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'want-end';
    Data ;
    datas ;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  weatherAPi = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=6cb36b639ee172ba6bc892bec0636b76'

    getWeather = () => {
      this.Data= this.http.get(this.weatherAPi).subscribe( data =>  {
        this.Data = data;
       console.log(this.Data)
     })
    }


   ngOnInit(){
    this.getWeather()
   }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
     <button (click)="getWeather()">clcik me</button>
  <h2 *ngFor="let data of Data ">{{ data}}</h2>



[data showing up in console][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQpzS.png
```

Comment: Show `console.log(this.Data)` output

Comment: You are trying to iterate over an observable and then later over an instance returned from that observable which is clearly *not* an array. What is it you are trying to display *exactly*? Why are you trying to use `*ngFor` in your component (to show... )?

Comment: @AdritaSharma  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQpzS.png

Comment: @Igor im only trying to display the data in the browser, is working in the console.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQpzS.png

Comment: You want to display which data in browser? weather??

Comment: @AdritaSharma please the data showing in the console, i hope you have seen it, so the weather i want to display

Comment: If you want to display everythin,? Be specific

Comment: @AdritaSharma the weather and country , main:
humidity,pressure,temp!

Comment: Learning how to program by trial and error using a technical help forum as your primary resource is no way to go about it. Go and follow a couple of tutorials first like the one on the [angular site](https://angular.io/tutorial). Once you understand the fundamentals come back and try to solve your problem again and if you feel a need to post a question on [so] be sure to ask a *specific* question.

Comment: @Igor thank you for suggestion , i think everybody learning to program come across errors one way or the other and probably you never come across an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the response you get from the `Weather API` is an `object` an not an `Array`. Therefore it is not iterable.

### Updated

You try to iterate over the object which is not feasible in `Angular`.

There are 2 things you could do:

#### 1. Use the [`KeyValuePairPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) to show a list of key value. Here is one of my [favorite explanation](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/pipes/built-in-pipes/) on how they work and how to build one.

In your template

```
<button (click)="getWeather()">clcik me</button>
<h2 *ngFor="let data of Data | keyvalue">{{data.key}}: {{data.value}}</h2>
```

Note that this approach will only display the value associated with a key. Meaning that an array will be displayed as `[...]`

#### 2. Display only the information you might want to display using `interpolation`.

In you template you coudl write

```
<button (click)="getWeather()">clcik me</button>
<h2>Current temperature: {{Data.main.temp}}</h2>
<h2>Wind speed: {{Data.wind.speed}}</h2>
```

To really up you game let the handling of the `Observable` to the `async pipe`.
- https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe
- https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-async-pipe/

### Edit

Here is [an example of what could be implemented](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58085920?file=src%2Fapp) in order to make this work.

Here are some link you might be interested in:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Thank you! I would go through the links first  on share code if i still dont get it.

Comment: Thank you so much it's working and showing up. i will figure the rest out ! cheers  :)

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through `weather` array, in addition, maybe it would be better to put your iterable data into `<p>` tag and use :

```
<button (click)="getWeather()">click me</button>
<ng-container *ngIf="Data && Data.weather && Data.weather.length > 0">
   <p *ngFor="let data of Data.weather">
      {{data}}
   </p>
</ng-container>
```

UPDATE:

It looks like you have the following structure

```
demo = {
    'key1': [{'key11':'value11'}, {'key12':'value12'}],
    'key2': [{'key21':'value21'}, {'key22':'value22'}],
  }
```

If so, try to use `keyvalue` pipe to help you iterate through objects:

```
<button (click)="getWeather()">click me</button>
<ng-container *ngIf="Data && Data.weather && Data.weather.length > 0">
   <p *ngFor="let item of Data.weather  | keyvalue">
         Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>          
   </p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Hey thank you, it's displaying and it im getting this message [object Object], do you mind checking up

Comment: it means that you display the `object` inside the array. You have to decompe it if you want to use it.

Comment: @StepUp  this the image link ===  i.stack.imgur.com/cQpzS.png

Comment: just saw ! Thank you so much! @StepUp , i have at least learnt something :)

Comment: @Joye feel free to upvote if you feel that my reply was helpful. This is the way how you can appreciate at stackoverflow. [How to upvote at stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)  :)